# youtube API functions just stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am making a web app based on Youtube AS3 APIs. Everything was going well and now suddenly all my player functions have stopped working. No event apart from "onYouTubePlayerAPIReady" is being called. 
I have buttons to control the volume of the video now the give me the error" player.getVolume() is not a function". I am able to sucessfully load a video and play it, but nothing more.

```
var h = ($("#ytplayer").width()*(9/16));
            player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
                   height: h,
                   videoId: currentlyPlaying,
                   playerVars: {
                    wmode: 'opaque',
                    autoplay: '1',
                    vq: 'small',
                    controls: '0',
                    iv_load_policy: '3',
                    rel: '0'
                },
                events: {
                        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                        }
            });
            makeControlsLive();

function makeControlsLive(){
    /*Make controls live*/
    logThis("Making ocntrols live now...");
    $("#vol_up").click( function(){
        if(player){
            var currentVol = player.getVolume();
            if((currentVol+10) <= 100){
                player.setVolume(currentVol+10);
                $("#vol_value").text((currentVol+10)+"%");
                $("#vol_mute").text(" mute ");
            }
        }
    });

    $("#vol_down").click( function(){
        if(player){
            var currentVol = player.getVolume();
            if((currentVol-10) >= 0){
                player.setVolume(currentVol-10);
                $("#vol_value").text((currentVol-10)+"%");
            }
        }
    });

    $("#vol_mute").click( function(){
        if(player){
            if(player.isMuted()){
                $("#vol_mute").text(" mute ");
                player.unMute();
            }
            else{
                $("#vol_mute").text(" unmute ");
                player.mute();
            }
        }
    });
}

    function onPlayerStateChange(newState) {
    alert(player.getPlayerState());
}
```

Has someone faced a simialr problem ? Is there a chance there is a bug with the youtube servers ?

Comment: is player a global variable? I had a similar "nothing happens" problem when I tried to wrap the whole youtube code in a function. then I found somewhere that all youtube functions and the player object itself is expected in the global scope.

Comment: yes player is a global variable. i define it as var player; on top of the this js script. The thing is player is accessible, i have it logged and checked that it is not null, just my API calls are failing, and they used to work without issue, just suddenly started failing.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem my code was working perfectly for month and then a few days ago it just stopped and the seek to function to loop the video again just doesn't work anymore my bet is google has messed around with it the youtube api team has a reputation for changing things without announcing the change and leave little documentation on new changes as of yet i have no idea how to fix it and it seem no one else does either but code doesn't just break over night they have obviously changed something.